# Unable to access files in Samsung Galaxy Android 4.0

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, storage

I am connecting a Samsung Galaxy Note II(Android 4.0, Ice Cream Sandwich) to Ubuntu 12.04 laptop through USB. I am able to see the directories like Music, files, Bluetooth, ShareViaWiFi etc. I also see a message at the top right corner which says **"These files are on a digital audio player"** but when I open these directories I am unable to see any file. I want to copy a media file located in **ShareViaWiFi** folder to my Ubuntu laptop. But I am unable to see the file when I open the folder in Ubuntu. I can see the file in the Samsung Galaxy, so I know it is there for sure.

Comment: Are you a pretty linux-savvy ubuntu user? If you are, you can mount the phone's internal hard drive to your system and then access it through terminal.

Comment: I tried the command 'df -h' but the samsung storage does not show up in the output. I would like to try out your suggestion if you could tell me which commands to execute.

Comment: You most likely use MTP. If I'm correct, you might want to add the 'mtp' tag to your question, and then follow it for related questions. There are several options provided already. As you either use USB, you might also want to take a look into [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16757), and especially watch for QtADB there (graphical ADB frontend which includes a.o. a file manager).

Answer (score 1):

To start make sure your device is unplugged. Then run:

```
df -h
```

that will show you the list of currently mounted devices. Now plug in your device and run the same command again. You should see that there is a new device mounted. Now all you have to do is `cd` into that mount point to access the files. Here is my example output:

```
john-macbookpro:~ John$ df -h
Filesystem                          Size   Used  Avail Capacity  iused     ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2                       297Gi   68Gi  229Gi    23% 17872734  60060168   23%   /

#plugged in device

john-macbookpro:~ John$ df -h
Filesystem                          Size   Used  Avail Capacity  iused     ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2                       297Gi   68Gi  229Gi    23% 17872734  60060168   23%   /
/dev/disk3s1                       983Mi   13Mi  970Mi     2%      512         0  100%   /Volumes/BACKUP ONLY
john-macbookpro:~ John$ cd /Volumes/BACKUP\ ONLY/
john-macbookpro:BACKUP ONLY John$ ls
hello.txt
john-macbookpro:BACKUP ONLY John$ cp hello.txt /Users/John/Documents/
john-macbookpro:BACKUP ONLY John$ cat /Users/John/Documents/hello.txt 
Hello!
```

If for some reason your device is not getting mounted, you should try to download ADB:

- http://www.xda-developers.com/android/installing-adb-on-ubuntu-the-easy-way/

run ADB and it should try to manage your Android device.

```
adb start
```